# Passing array to delegate method as ref

Tags: c#, arrays, delegates, ref

I attempted to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem) HackerRank challenge, and found a C++ algorithm by @DNKpp posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183790/hackerrank-leaderboard-challenge). 
This is a working C# version:

```
class Demo
{
    delegate int MyDelegate(int[] _scores, int _aScore);

    static int[] climbingLeaderboard(int[] scores, int[] alice)
    {
        int[] result = new int[alice.Count()];

        var distinctScores = scores.Distinct().ToArray();

        MyDelegate locateRanking = (scoresArr, aliceScore) => {
            var itr = Array.Find(scoresArr, el => el <= aliceScore);
            var idx = Array.FindIndex(scoresArr, score => score == itr);
            return idx == -1 ? distinctScores.Count() + 1 : idx + 1;
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < alice.Count(); i++)
        {
            result[i] = locateRanking(distinctScores, alice[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] scores = { 100, 90, 90, 80, 75, 60 };
        int[] alice = { 50, 65, 77, 90, 102 };
        int[] result = new int[alice.Count()];

        result = climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice);
    }
}
```

The `climbingLeaderboard` function signature is fixed. 
But I'd like to pass `scores` as a `ref` into `locateRanking`. Is it possible? I'm getting an error. Also, this C# version is reaching a timeout on HackerRank. How can I improve it?

Comment: "...I'm getting an error..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: An array is a reference type, so you are already passing a reference to it. I don't see much point in passing a reference to a reference. Is that what you want? Also, there is no code here that could "time out." Do you mean that the program takes too long to run?

Comment: What benefit would passing it in as `ref` give you? And you can't change the method signature by changing the delegate.

Comment: Where is locateRanking method?

Comment: @John Wu, Accepted. I misunderstood the Array in C#.

Comment: It fails 4 out of 11 test cases due to timeout

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this? (I've Added ref keyword in the delegate and function):

```
class Demo
{
    delegate int MyDelegate(ref int[] _scores, int _aScore);

    static int[] climbingLeaderboard(int[] scores, int[] alice)
    {
        int[] result = new int[alice.Count()];

        var distinctScores = scores.Distinct().ToArray();

        MyDelegate locateRanking = (ref int[] scoresArr, int aliceScore) => {
            var itr = Array.Find(scoresArr, el => el <= aliceScore);
            var idx = Array.FindIndex(scoresArr, score => score == itr);
            return idx == -1 ? distinctScores.Count() + 1 : idx + 1;
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < alice.Count(); i++)
        {
            result[i] = locateRanking(ref distinctScores, alice[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] scores = { 100, 90, 90, 80, 75, 60 };
        int[] alice = { 50, 65, 77, 90, 102 };
        int[] result = new int[alice.Count()];

        result = climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works too, but after @John Wu comments, I suppose it is no longer needed. The timeout is still there

Comment: Sorry, new here (actively), jsut saw you said the signature of the function must stay fixed.. is it means using ref keyword considered a diffrent signature

Comment: Only the `climbingLeaderboard` signature is fixed. `MyDelegate` can be changed